# Have docker container connect to network devices

Tags: docker

I am trying to make a few docker containers to hold some of my everyday tooling. But a lot of my tools depend on being able to connect to devices  (via wifi) to pull data.

I have been doing research and am rather confused trying to understand what, if anything, would need to be done to support this scenario. I know usually docker containers are the server not the client. But i have read about people doing the opposite.

I am trying to figure out what kind of changes/configuration would be needed to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Docker will create a virtual network on your physical server; e.g. the `docker0` interface. That happens in `bridge` mode, it allows this interface to connect to the internet through your `eth0` device. `eth0` is the physical system interface; everything related to your local as well as global network will pass through the `eth0` physical interface.

If you want to access the internet or your local network inside your running docker container, you have to add `nameserver` as per your physical system `/etc/resolv.conf` file during startup of the docker daemon. This way, everything you can normally access with your physical system you'll be able to access with the docker container.

One more thing, you have to expose ports when you start up your docker container so that it can pull data from outside the docker network with the help of the `eth0` interface. All this configuration is automatically taken care with the help of `iptables`. Docker will adds `iptables rules` to forward traffic from `docker0` to `eth0` and your service will work perfectly.

**Example**

```
docker run -it --name "$container_name" -d -h "$host_name" -p 9080:9080 -p 1522:1522 "$image_name"
```

In the above case, my application is pulling data from `$host_name` via port `1522`. `-p 1522:1522` means it will send request to port `1522` on the physical machine, similarly, the physical machine will send this request to the network hosted machine on the same `1522` port."

Comment: So I am confused by the nameserver. Do you have links for configuring this on windows? I thought -p opened connections on the host machine that are tied to the docker container. Are these bidirectional?

Comment: In this link you will get docker configuration with `dns opts` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon