# Docker container can't connect to DB on external network

Tags: networking, docker, pentaho

I have a docker container (Windows 10) running on a new docker network I've defined. The container runs a pentaho transformation that tries to connect to an OpenEdge database.

Within my transformation set up, I have the following DB connection parameters:

```
#Connection URL
jdbc:datadirect:openedge://<machine_name>:<machine_port>;databaseName=<db_name>;user=<user_name>;password=<pass_word>
#Driver
com.ddtek.jdbc.openedge.OpenEdgeDriver
#User
user_name
#Pass
password
```

I have the correct drivers in the pentaho lib folder with the correct permissions.

I'm running the transformation from docker-compose and successfully connecting to a mysql DB in another container:

```
version: "2"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: my-pdi-mysql
    networks:
      - my-pdi-network
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=tbitter
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mysql-db
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./goldbi:/var/lib/mysql
  pdi:
    image: my-pdi-image-with-pan:latest
    container_name: my-pdi-container
    networks:
      - my-pdi-network
    volumes:
      - C:\Docker-Pentaho\resource:/home/pentaho/data-integration/resources
    #entrypoint: 
    #  - C:\Docker-Pentaho\docker-entrypoint-2.sh

networks:
  my-pdi-network:
```

How do I also connect to a DB on an external machine on the same network as the host from my container? I've done a lot of 'googling' on this but I'm a bit confused!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of the command `docker ps`

Comment: I got a little further with this and eventually found this here on SO; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43465395/have-docker-container-connect-to-network-devices and modified my container call accordingly;  docker container run -it -h <host-name> -p <host-port>:<host-port> --name my-pdi-container --user root --network my-pdi-network -v C:\Docker-Pentaho\resource:/home/pentaho/data-integration/resources my-pdi-image-with-pan

Comment: C:\Docker-Pentaho>docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
c2ea7c7157b1        my-pdi-image-with-pan   "../scripts/docker..."   40 seconds ago      Exited (3) 13 seconds ago                       my-pdi-container

Comment: I now get a new error but I'm further along than before; 2017/05/31 15:27:30 - Read Gold Orders.0 - Error connecting to database: (using class com.ddtek.jdbc.openedge.OpenEdgeDriver)
2017/05/31 15:27:30 - Read Gold Orders.0 - [DataDirect][OpenEdge JDBC Driver]Error establishing socket to host and port: scorpio:12460. Reason: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2017/05/31 15:27:30 - Read Gold Orders.0 - ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : Error initializing step [Read Gold Orders]

Comment: @MarkBeynon have you found any solution?