# docker app serving on https and connecting to external rethinkdb

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rethinkdb

I'm trying to launch a docker container that is running a tornado app in python 3.
It serves a few API calls and is writing data to a rethinkdb service on the system. RethinkDB does not run inside a container.
The system it runs on is ubuntu 16.04.

Whenever I tried to launch the docker with docker-compose, it would crash saying the connection to localhost:28015 was refused.
I went researching the problem and realized that docker has its own network and that external connections must be configured prior to launching the container.
I used this command from a [a question I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43465395/have-docker-container-connect-to-network-devices) to make it work:

```
docker run -it --name "$container_name" -d -h "$host_name" -p 9080:9080 -p 1522:1522 "$image_name"
```

I've changed the container name, host name, ports and image name to fit my own application.
Now, the docker is not crashing, but I have two problems:

1. I can't reach it from a browser by pointing to https://localhost/login
2. I lose the docker-compose usage. This is problematic if we want to add more services that talk to each other in the future.

So, how do I launch a docker that can talk to my rethinkdb database without putting that DB into a container? 
Please, let me know if you need more information to answer this question.
I'd appreciate your guidance in this.
The end result is that the docker will serve requests coming over https.
for exmaple I have an end-point called /getURL. 
The request includes a token verified in the DB. The URL is like this:
https://some-domain.com/getURL
after verification with the DB it will send back a relevant response.
the docker needs to be able to talk on 443 and also on 28015 with the rethinkdb service.

(Since 443 and https include the use of certificates, I'd appreciate a solution that handles this on regular http with some random port too and I'll take it from there)
Thanks!

P.S. The service works when I launch it without a docker on pycharm it's the docker configuration I have problems with.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
I needed to add this so that the container can connect to both the database and the rethinkdb:

```
--network="host"
```

Since this solution works for me right now, but it isn't the best solution, I won't mark this as the answer for now.